# Google translate widget appears twice

Tags: responsive-design, google-translate

I have a responsive site that uses the google translate widget. The weird thing is that for some time the widget now appears twice, and this seem to be related to the responsive design because if I place the same widget code on a simple html page it only appears once. I have no idea on how to solve this. Has anyone come across this?

Update.

I have discovered that this is caused by `jquery.themepunch.showbizpro.min.js`, if I remove that one the widget only appears once. I have not found a way to fix this yet but there might be a way. I found this piece of code.

```
<script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement(
        { pageLanguage: 'sv' },
        'google_translate_element'
    );

    /*
        To remove the "powered by google",
        uncomment one of the following code blocks.
        NB: This breaks Google's Attribution Requirements:
        https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/attribution#attribution-and-logos
    */

    // Native (but only works in browsers that support query selector)
    if(typeof(document.querySelector) == 'function') {
        document.querySelector('.goog-logo-link').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        document.querySelector('.goog-te-gadget').setAttribute('style', 'font-size: 0');
    }

    //If you have jQuery - works cross-browser - uncomment this
    jQuery('.goog-logo-link').css('display', 'none');
    jQuery('.goog-te-gadget').css('font-size', '0');
}
</script>
```

This code remove the logo, so I'm thinking that if I use javascript I could check and remove duplicate occurrences of `<select class="goog-te-combo">` then I would only have one left, is that possible?

Comment: Please provide us some code.

Comment: I have discovered that this is caused by jquery.themepunch.showbizpro.min.js, if remove that one the widget only appears once. I have not found a way to fix this yet but there might be a way... I found this piece of code..

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me using Bootstrap. I had two instances of the Google Translate code - one instance for larger screen sizes and another that was only visible for smaller screens.  Both showed up regardless of screen size.  Bootstrap classes like visible-xs and hidden-xs do not seem to affect the display of the Google Translate button.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a global counter and make sure it's only called once.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var duplicate_google_translate_counter = 0;//this stops google adding button multiple times

    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
       if (duplicate_google_translate_counter == 0) {
          new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
       }
       duplicate_google_translate_counter++;
    }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on RoR. Problem caused by cashing pages with turbolinks. I solved it with deprecating cashing all links in  (when script loading it adds attr "data-turbolinks="false" to the body-tag)

Answer (score 0):

**Hello to all!** I had the same issue and I KNOW is not the best practice but I fixed it with CSS just adding overflow: hidden and a right border on it.

**It visually fix the problem until we get a solution and really saved time diving into JS files.** Hope it works for you too. Cheers!